# Unable to compare String value to Int value in karate. How to convert Int value to String value

Tags: karate

Json response number is in "89734873", but while validating with a number.
Throwing error as cannot compare with string, until here it is fine. But how to convert from number to string in karate for validation

Comment: please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#floats-and-integers